He reached into his pocket for a dime

He reached into his pocket for a dime.

Can I replace the sentence above as below?

He reached for a dime into his pocket. or


Into his pocket, he reached for a dime.


There are a lot of questions about ordering prepositional phrases; there's no firm rule but generally you put things closely connected to the verb next to the verb and less connected things (e.g. modifying the sentence as a whole) or less important things later. So motion is often before purpose or time, unless motion isn't the important bit.

You can use into in the first example, but not in the third. That's because into describes where he's reaching in the first example. In the third, it's describing where the dime is located. Similarly, you should use into in the second example, but it sounds very awkward and I wouldn't recommend using that construct at all.

He reached into his pocket for a dime.
(describes where he reached)


Into his pocket, he reached for a dime.
(where he reached, but very awkward - don't use)


He reached for a dime in his pocket.
(describes where the dime was located)

(I modified my previous answer because of one of the comments.)
